# Unexpected results for Project Euler #17 (Python 3 vs Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I was working through Project Euler #17, trying to find the answer, not really aiming for efficiency. However, after reading over every single number (I think) printed, I can't find what is leading to an answer exactly 100 characters over the correct answer. So then I decided to come on SO to find out, and when I compiled it online using Python 2.7 on accident, I got a drastically different result! I'm not sure why compiling it in Python 2.7 leads to a significantly wrong answer, and in Python 3 it's barely off. Anyway here are the two places I compiled online:

**Correct answer, My Python 3 answer, My Python 2.7 answer:** 21124, 21224, 18632

**Python 3:** http://ideone.com/ugfSV1

**Python 2.7:** I don't know how to share it, so you'll just have to copy and paste the code below manually http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php

**Here's my algorithm:**

```
import time

start = time.time()

singles = {0: "",
           1: "one",
           2: "two",
           3: "three",
           4: "four",
           5: "five",
           6: "six",
           7: "seven",
           8: "eight",
           9: "nine",
           10: "ten",
           11: "eleven",
           12: "twelve",
           13: "thirteen",
           14: "fourteen",
           15: "fifteen",
           16: "sixteen",
           17: "seventeen",
           18: "eighteen",
           19: "nineteen"}

tens = {2: "twenty",
        3: "thirty",
        4: "fourty",
        5: "fifty",
        6: "sixty",
        7: "seventy",
        8: "eighty",
        9: "ninety"}

hundred = "hundred"
count = 0

for num in range(1001):

    if len(str(num)) == 4:
        word = "onethousand"

    elif len(str(num)) == 3:
        first = singles[num // 100] + hundred

        if num % 100 == 0:
            first = singles[num // 100] + hundred
            second = ""

        elif num % 100 < 20:
            first += "and"
            second = singles[num % 100]

        elif num % 100 < 100:
            first += "and"
            second = tens[(num % 100) // 10]

        if isinstance(((num % 100) / 10), float) and (num % 100 > 20):
            third = singles[(num % 100) % 10]
        else:
            third = ""

        word = first + second + third

    elif len(str(num)) == 2:
        if num > 19:
            first = tens[num // 10]
            second = singles[num % 10]
            word = first + second
        else:
            word = singles[num]

    elif len(str(num)) == 1:
        word = singles[num]

    print(word)
    count += len(word)

print("The total number of letters in all words from 1 to 1000 is: {}".format(
    count))

print("Time: {}".format(time.time() - start))
```

Comment: `"forty"` shouldn't have a `u`..

Comment: @DSM Unbelievable lol thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isinstance(((num % 100) / 10), float)` is always true on Python 3 and always false on Python 2 (assuming `num` is `int`). See [PEP 238](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) about this change.

Comment: Why is it always false on Python 2? And any idea where the extra 100 characters are coming from for Python 3?

Comment: Python 2 does integer division on ints.

Answer (score -1):

A few errors.

"forty" not "fourty"

"one thousand" not "onethousand"

"twenty-one" not "twentyone" you have no logic to insert hyphens

"one hundred" not "onehundred" your and logic does not pad around ***and*** with spaces

"one hundred and one" not "onehundredandone" again, missing logic to insert spaces

"two hundred and one" not "twohundredone" missing logic to insert ***and*** for 200-999

Comment: That is on purpose. Project Euler specifies to ignore spaces and hyphens so why would I bother taking the time to add them? The only real error is "fourty". Also, the "and" is there... Not sure why you don't see them

Comment: You do it the right way, because it is more useful and pleasing. Yes, you don't count them either for the stated problem.

Comment: Do you know what Project Euler is? I'm not trying to use it for anything else, and even if I did have a use for this tool, I would be wasting time trying to reinvent something that already exists. Again, my code is correct for the problem minus the spelling error in "fourty" which was pointed out in a comment long ago

Comment: Ah, yes. I remember the "fourty" error. Nailed a bunch of others who posted in the forum, from what I remember.